# How to use Yacc to translate a language to C++?

Tags: c++, yacc, translate

This is a more general question since I don't really know how to get started.  Basically, I have to use Yacc to interpret/translate a made-up language called CALC, which can perform arithmetic operations on variables and then print them out.  I've already got the interpretation working, but the second part of my project is to write a C++ file that contains all of the instructions in the original file, translated.

My question is, how do I do that?  Do I write to file inside the code for my grammar rules, or do I do it inside main?  I've been trying to do it inside of the grammar rule code, but I'm finding that the data is being written to file backwards (that is, if I declare four variables, the program prints out the last one declared in the original program first, and so on).

Comment: This is really not clear.  If you've solved the Yacc part, why are you asking about Yacc?

Comment: It is still Yacc-related.  I've interpreted the language, but I have to use Yacc to write a C++ file that does the same thing as the given program.

Comment: @user1174511 If you have already implemented interpretation, then you already have some form of abstract data structure containing the code (for example, an AST or ASG). You can just walk this structure and "serialize" it to C++.

Answer (score 2):

Well, Yacc does do a bottom-up parse.

You broadly have two choices:

1. You can output results as you are now, when input causes a reduction and the attached code is executed, but then you will need to reorder things all the time.
2. You can build an [abstract syntax tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) in your rules and then traverse it in-order. This is the usual approach.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this in two phases: use yacc to create parse tree, then walk the tree to output whatever needed to be output.

Answer (score 0):

> data is being written to file backwards

This particular bit sounds like you've chosen a different construct than you wanted. Yacc allows both left and right recursion, which lets you (for example) parse a list in the order you see each item (left recursion), or in the opposite order. Here's an example of the right recursion you're probably doing now:

```
list : ITEM
     | ITEM list
```

Notice that when this subgrammar sees an ITEM in the input, it doesn't know which of these two productions to use just based on that -- they both start with an ITEM. So, the parser looks ahead one token. If the next token is not an ITEM, then it knows to use the first production. But if the next token IS an ITEM, then it must process the second production. But that production has the nonterminal `list` in it, which means the parser doesn't actually reduce at all, but pushes that first ITEM on the stack and goes looking for another `list`.

The upshot of this is, if you give this subgrammar a list of ITEM tokens, it will just keep pushing them on the stack until it finally sees an ITEM that isn't followed by another ITEM. At that point, the final ITEM will be reduced by the first production (and thereby turned into a `list`, and all the other ITEMs will be reduced one by one by the second production. On to left recursion.

```
list : ITEM         /* matches first ITEM in list */
     | list ITEM    /* matches all other ITEMs in list */
```

This time, when the parser sees an ITEM, only one of the `list` productions starts with an ITEM, so it will immediately reduce by the first production, turning that ITEM into a `list`. Now, if there is another ITEM in the input stream, it will be trying to match a `list` followed by an ITEM, and that exactly matches the second production.

These are the common idioms for parsing simple lists. Note that if your list is "zero or more" instead of "one or more", then you would simply use an empty production instead of the one containing a single ITEM. With left recursion (what you usually want), having a separate production that matches the first item gives you a convenient place to put an action that, for example, initializes an array that is going to hold all the ITEMs that (might) follow.